# Is there a method for looking up a value in a list box based on criteria from one of the list box columns?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list box with a total of 5 columns with email addresses in column 2. I have some code that loops through that column and adds the email addresses to the recipients in an email. It works great but now I need to only add email addresses that contain a certain value in list box column 5.

I have searched for look up methods but I can't find anything for list boxes.

This is the code without any look up criteria:

```
strEmailRecipients = ""
For N = 0 To Me.lstContacts.ListCount - 1
    strEmailRecipients = strEmailRecipients & "; " & Me.lstContacts.Column(2, N)
Next N
```

Is there any way I can modify the code to only add values from column 2 that meet a certain criteria in column 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question (maybe I'm missing something).

Just use the same method to read a column value as you already have in place, with a `If`.

```
strEmailRecipients = ""
For N = 0 To Me.lstContacts.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lstContacts.Column(5, N) = "a certain value" Then
        strEmailRecipients = strEmailRecipients & "; " & Me.lstContacts.Column(2, N)
    End If
Next N
```

Comment: Thank you, that was so simple. I was over thinking it way too much.